# Program not working for large files in C

Tags: c, file, fopen

I'm using the following program in C to filter a log file with about 200,000 lines. But the program stops responding after about 12000 lines. Any explanations why does this happen and any solution to it?
The code is compiled in GCC (windows).

PS: The code is executing properly and giving desired output for small files.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int check(char *url)
{
    //some code to filter the data and return either 0 or 1 depending upon input
}

int main()
{
    FILE *fpi, *fpo;
    fpi=fopen("access.log","r");
    fpo=fopen("edited\\filter.txt","w");
    char date[11],time[9],ip[16],url[500],temp[3];
    while(!feof(fpi))
    {
        printf(".");
        fscanf(fpi," %s %s %s %s %s %s",date,time,temp,ip,temp,url);
        if(check(url)) 
            fprintf(fpo,"%s %s %s %s %s %s\n",date,time,temp,ip,temp,url);
    }
    fclose(fpi);
    fclose(fpo);
    printf("\n\n\nDONE! :)");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the file format is correct? `fscanf` doesn't allow for any aberrations. Try removing the first 12000 lines to see if it's a problem in the data. Also try making your buffer sizes bigger.

Comment: FWIW, this sounds like a job for `awk`.

Comment: Oh yeah, i increased the buffer size and its working... Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible that one of the lines in the input file contains a field that is larger than the string variable you pass to `fscanf()`. It might result in a buffer overflow, which later results in an infinite loop somewhere. Just a speculation. I suggest you delimit `%s` in the `fscanf()` format string with the maximum length of the output string variable.

For example, this will make sure that there are no buffer overflows and that the resulted strings terminate:

```
 fscanf(fpi," %10s %8s %2s %15s %49s %2s", date, time, temp, ip, temp, url);
 date[10] = '\0';
 time[8] = '\0'; 
 ip[15] = '\0'; 
 temp[2] = '\0'; 
 url[499] = '\0';
```

Also, you are reading temp twice. The latter read will override the former. Is this what you intended?

Another improvement, assuming that the input file is line-terminated, and each log is in a separate line, is to use `fgets()` in order to read a line and only then use `sscanf()` on the intermediate buffer. This way you ensure that no formatting errors extend beyond a single line. Also, sscanf returns the number of read items, in your case - 6. It's would be safer to check the return value.

Comment: You might use `getline` to read a whole line (at least on Linux & recent POSIX; I have no idea if it works on Windows).

Comment: `getline` is easily implemented in terms of `fgets`, and `getdelim` can even be implemented manually in terms of `getc` or using `fscanf` with `%[`. So the point is, if a platform lacks them, you can always drop-in replacements built on lower-level functions. The `fgets` version should be roughly the same speed as a native `getline`, but using `getc` will surely be slow.